# Firefox OS apps - html canvas - touch also moves page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, firefox-os

I made a firefox OS app with the home page screen [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpCuE.jpg) in imitation of the stock android's unlock swipe feature.

The touch event works, however the issue is that tapping on the canvas works as expected. But if I try to imitate the swipe gesture, the complete web page moves instead of sending multiple touch events to the canvas.

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-top:3%;" >
    <canvas id="paint" style="border:1px solid #000000; display: inline;"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; margin-top:25px;">
    <p style="bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center; color:purple;">
        <a href="#/credits/"><strong>About</strong></a>
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("paint")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // ... init part of the code

    function main_function(event){
        // calculate size and shadow of the 
        // circles according to the position of the touch
        // and then redraw the canvas
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", main_function);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", main_function);
</script>
```

How do I ensure that on making a swiping gesture, all the signals are caught by the canvas, and doesn't result in the page shifting up/down?

Answer (score 0):

A good introduction to touch handling is on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

There you'll also find the information that you have to add `event.preventDefault()` in your event handlers "to keep the browser from continuing to process the touch event". This includes scrolling.